# D3.js Custom SVG as background

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm wondering whether I can have a custom SVG as background to a d3.js instead of declaring a new one?

So instead of declaring a new SVG before starting to generate the chart:

```
var svg = d3.selectAll('#my_div')
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 400)
            .attr("height", 400)
            .append("g");
```

Could I instead, append a custom svg.  Such as [this](http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/home_149955#term=house&page;=1&position;=29)?

I realise I can get round it by appending an image to my new svg but I was wondering if I could override that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could hard code the SVG in the HTML with the background you want and then in D3 select that svg...

```
d3.select("#my_div svg")
    // do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

To paint over an existent SVG, just select it:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg");
```

And use that selection to draw your elements.

Here is a demo, the existent SVG is the star, the circles are added by the D3 code:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var circles = svg.selectAll("foo")
 .data(d3.range(6))
 .enter()
 .append("circle")
 .attr("cy", 100)
 .attr("cx", (d,i)=>i*30 + 20)
 .attr("r", 12)
 .attr("fill", "orangered")
        .attr("stroke", "black");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
</svg>
```